# How to concatenate arrays from cell arrays in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

I am new to Matlab and was trying to concatenate array from cell arrays. I have done it as shown below.

```
S = load('input_file.mat');
c = struct2cell(S);
v = cell2mat(c(1,1));
temp = v(1:500,1:600);

v = cell2mat(c(3,1));
temp1 = v(1:500,1:600);

v = cell2mat(c(2,1));
temp2 = v(1:500,1:600);

v = cell2mat(c(4,1));
temp3 = v(1:500,1:600);

array1 = vertcat(temp,temp1);
array2 = vertcat(temp2,temp3);
```

But i guess there should be a better way or a direct function call which can get me the same result as i am getting from the code shown?

Comment: Can you give a small example with all variables contained?

Comment: All variables are integers

Comment: You helped me find horzcat and vertcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very specific task, not very general, unless I'm missing the pattern. Starting after `struct2cell`:

```
C3 = cellfun(@(x)x(1:500,1:600),c,'uni',0);
array1 = vertcat(C3{[1 3]});
array2 = vertcat(C3{[2 4]});
```

Although, you could probably get rid of your initial `structfun` if you replace `cellfun` above with `structfun`, taking `s` as an input.  It simply operates on each field.